# SAS token - Signature fields not well formed

Tags: java, azure

I want to generate a SAS token for access to my blob container where are some of my media files.

So I created a class SharedAccessSignature.java with this code:

```
public class SharedAccessSignature
{
    private final String signature;

    private final String signedPermission;
    private final String signedStart;
    private final String signedExpiry;
    private final String signedIdentifier;
    private final String signedIp;
    private final String signedProtocol;
    private final String signedVersion;
    private final String signedResource;

    private SharedAccessSignature(SasBuilder builder)
    {
        signedPermission = formatAsUrlParameter("sp", builder.signedPermission);
        signedStart = formatAsUrlParameter("st", builder.signedStart);
        signedExpiry = formatAsUrlParameter("se", builder.signedExpiry);
        signedIdentifier = formatAsUrlParameter("si", builder.signedIdentifier);
        signedIp = formatAsUrlParameter("sip", builder.signedIp);
        signedProtocol = formatAsUrlParameter("spr", builder.signedProtocol);
        signedVersion = formatAsUrlParameter("sv", builder.signedVersion);
        signedResource = formatAsUrlParameter("sr", builder.signedResource);

        signature = "sig=" + new SasBuilder().encodeUtf8(builder.signature);
    }

    private String formatAsUrlParameter(String parameterKey, String parameterValue)
    {
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(parameterValue))
        {
            return parameterKey + "=" + parameterValue + "&";
        }
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return new StringBuilder()
            .append(signedVersion)
            .append(signedResource)
            .append(signedStart)
            .append(signedExpiry)
            .append(signedPermission)
            .append(signedIp)
            .append(signedProtocol)
            .append(signedIdentifier)
            .append(signature)
            .toString();
    }

    public static class SasBuilder
    {
        private String signature = "";

        private String signedPermission = "";
        private String signedStart = "";
        private String signedExpiry = "";
        private String canonicalizedResource = "";
        private String signedIdentifier = "";
        private String signedIp = "";
        private String signedProtocol = "";
        private String signedVersion = "";
        private String signedResource = "";

        public SasBuilder signedVersion(String signedVersion)
        {
            this.signedVersion = signedVersion;
            return this;
        }

        public SasBuilder signedPermission(String signedPermission)
        {
            this.signedPermission = signedPermission;
            return this;
        }

        public SasBuilder canonicalizedResource(String canonicalizedResource)
        {
            this.canonicalizedResource = canonicalizedResource;
            return this;
        }

        public SasBuilder signedIp(String signedIp)
        {
            this.signedIp = signedIp;
            return this;
        }

        public SasBuilder signedProtocol(String signedProtocol)
        {
            this.signedProtocol = signedProtocol;
            return this;
        }

        public SasBuilder signedIdentifier(String signedIdentifier)
        {
            this.signedIdentifier = signedIdentifier;
            return this;
        }

        public SasBuilder signedExpiry(String signedExpiry)
        {
            this.signedExpiry = signedExpiry;
            return this;
        }

        public SasBuilder signedStart(String signedStart)
        {
            this.signedStart = signedStart;
            return this;
        }

        public SasBuilder signedResource(String signedResource)
        {
            this.signedResource = signedResource;
            return this;
        }

        public SharedAccessSignature build()
        {
            String toBeAsEnvironmentVariable_securityKey = "....";
            signature = generateSasSignature(toBeAsEnvironmentVariable_securityKey, stringToSign());
            checkPreconditions();
            return new SharedAccessSignature(this);
        }

        private String generateSasSignature(String key, String input)
        {
            SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");
            Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
            Mac sha256_HMAC = null;
            String hash = null;

            try
            {
                sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
                sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);
                hash = new String(encoder.encode(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(input.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
            }
            catch (InvalidKeyException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | IllegalStateException | UnsupportedEncodingException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return hash;
        }

        private String stringToSign()
        {
            StringBuilder strToSign = new StringBuilder();
            strToSign.append(signedPermission).append("\n");
            strToSign.append(signedStart).append("\n");
            strToSign.append(signedExpiry).append("\n");
            strToSign.append(canonicalizedResource).append("\n");
            strToSign.append(signedIdentifier).append("\n");
            strToSign.append(signedIp).append("\n");
            strToSign.append(signedProtocol).append("\n");
            strToSign.append(signedVersion).append("\n");
            strToSign.append("").append("\n");
            strToSign.append("").append("\n");
            strToSign.append("").append("\n");
            strToSign.append("").append("\n");
            strToSign.append("");
            return strToSign.toString();
        }

        private void checkPreconditions()
        {
            if (StringUtils.isBlank(signedVersion) || StringUtils.isBlank(signedResource) || StringUtils.isBlank(signedPermission) || StringUtils.isBlank(signedExpiry) || StringUtils.isBlank(signature))
            {
                throw new IllegalStateException("SAS Builder: SignedVersion, signedResource, SignedPermission, SignedExpiry, Signature must be set.");
            }
        }

        private String encodeUtf8(String textToBeEncoded)
        {
            try
            {
                return URLEncoder.encode(textToBeEncoded, "UTF-8");
            }
            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return textToBeEncoded;
        }
    }
}
```

And then I try to generate a SAS token like this:

```
SharedAccessSignature s = new SharedAccessSignature.SasBuilder()
        .signedPermission("rwd")
        .signedStart("2018-01-31T10:48:41Z")
        .signedExpiry("2018-04-06T18:48:41Z")
        .signedVersion("2015-04-05")
        .signedResource("b")
        .canonicalizedResource("/blob/myaccount")
        .signedProtocol("https")
        .build();
```

outcome:

```
sv=2015-04-05&sr=b&st=2018-01-31T10:48:41Z&se=2018-04-06T18:48:41Z&sp=rwd&spr=https&sig=kd09Y%2FTL5V%2F570VWRuEfq7XbEHvcgo4Z%2F2y9t4OswY8%3D
```

GET request:

```
https://account.blob.core.cloudapi.de/container/filename.mp4?sv=2015-04-05&sr=b&st=2018-01-31T10:48:41Z&se=2018-04-06T18:48:41Z&sp=rwd&spr=https&sig=kd09Y%2FTL5V%2F570VWRuEfq7XbEHvcgo4Z%2F2y9t4OswY8%3D
```

But as I am sending that request with this generated token there commes this Error from azure:

```
<Error>
 <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
 <Message>
   Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of 
   Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. 
 </Message>
 <AuthenticationErrorDetail>
   Signature did not match. String to sign used was rwd 2018-01-31T10:48:41Z 
   2018-04-06T18:48:41Z /blob/globalweb/..... https 2015-04-05
 </AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

#### EDIT:

I am desperate... I don´t understand it... What is wrong on this "string-to-sign"? Why the "Signature did not match"?

```
--------
rwd\n
2018-01-31T10:48:41Z\n
2018-04-06T18:48:41Z\n
/blob/globalweb/videos-martindale\n
\n
\n
https\n
2015-04-05\n
\n
\n
\n
\n

-------

//link: https://globalweb.blob.core.cloudapi.de/videos-martindale/somevideo.mp4?sv=2015-04-05&sr=c&st=2018-01-31T10:48:41Z&se=2018-04-06T18:48:41Z&sp=rwd&spr=https&sig=kd09Y%2FTL5V%2F570VWRuEfq7XbEHvcgo4Z%2F2y9t4OswY8%3D

<Error>
    <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
    <Message>
        Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:644e47a6-001e-0050-3f20-abc0f0000000 Time:2018-02-21T14:31:10.9429817Z
    </Message>
    <AuthenticationErrorDetail>
        Signature did not match. String to sign used was rwd 2018-01-31T10:48:41Z 2018-04-06T18:48:41Z /blob/globalweb/videos-martindale https 2015-04-05
    </AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

Comment: Can you share the code where you’re using this SAS token? Also share the SAS token generated by the code. Just obfuscate the sig portion of the token before sharing.

Comment: I've just updated the post

Comment: I see a few issues with your code: 1) You're using the permissions that are not applicable for `blob` resource. 2) The permissions you have specified are out of order. Based on the documentation, these permissions have to be in order. 3) I don't see canonical resource for which you're getting the token anywhere in your code. Please refer to this link for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/constructing-a-service-sas. HTH.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I did it and it still doesn't work... But this time comes another error message. I edited my post again.

Comment: I think the problem is coming because you're mixing Account SAS and Service SAS. Please try something for me: 1) Change `signedResource("b")` to `signedResource("c") and 2)  Change `canonicalizedResource("/blob/myaccount")` to `canonicalizedResource("/blob/myaccount/mycontainer")`. Let me know if that fixes your problem. If it doesn't then, please edit your question and include the latest code you're using. Instead of replacing the old code with latest code, please append the latest code to the question.

Comment: I´ve tried it but still the same behaviour and error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is on you `generateSasSignature` method. It should decode the key from `Base64`. Like the following:

```
public static String generateSasSignature(String key, String input) {
    SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(key), "HmacSHA256");
    Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
    Mac sha256_HMAC = null;
    String hash = null;

    try {
        sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);
        hash = new String(encoder.encode(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(input.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
    }
    catch (InvalidKeyException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | IllegalStateException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return hash;
}
```

Then, assuming you're interested in having access to the container called `mycontainer`, this is how you should do:

```
SharedAccessSignature s = new SharedAccessSignature.SasBuilder()
    .signedPermission("rwd")
    .signedStart("2018-01-31T10:48:41Z")
    .signedExpiry("2018-04-06T18:48:41Z")
    .signedVersion("2015-04-05")
    .signedResource("c")  // <<---- note here
    .canonicalizedResource("/blob/globalweb/mycontainer") // No ending slash!
    .signedProtocol("https")
    .build();
```

However, if you want to generate an Account SAS, the following code does the trick:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String accountName = "globalweb";
    String signedPermissions = "rl"; //read and list
    String signedService = "b";  //blob
    String signedResType = "sco";  //service, container, objects
    String start = "2018-02-22T17:16:25Z";
    String expiry = "2018-02-28T01:16:25Z";
    String signedIp = "";
    String protocol = "https";
    String signedVersion = "2017-07-29";

    String stringToSign = 
            accountName + "\n" +  
        signedPermissions + "\n" +  
        signedService + "\n" +  
        signedResType + "\n" +  
        start + "\n" +  
        expiry + "\n" +  
        signedIp + "\n" +  
        protocol + "\n" +  
        signedVersion + "\n";

    //outputs SAS Token
    System.out.println(
            "?sv="+signedVersion +
            "&ss="+signedService +
            "&srt="+signedResType + 
            "&sp="+signedPermissions +
            "&st="+start+
            "&se="+expiry+
            "&spr="+protocol+
            "&sig="+
            URLEncoder.encode(SasBuilder.generateSasSignature(MY_KEY_BASE64, stringToSign), "UTF-8"));
}
```

Comment: It was a great help. I had to tweak for things to work out at my end but if it weren't for this answer and above questions I would have spent another week on this. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Got this same error which led me to this post:

> 403 Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

In my case I had an `EncodeURI()` on the already encoded uri.

Removing this also fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this if you are using 12.5. I was able to get this working with the following:

```
try { 
    //Authenticate 
    StorageSharedKeyCredential credential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(this.getAzureAccountName(), this.getAzureAccountKey());

    //Get the Blob Service Client 
    BlobServiceClient client = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
                .endpoint(this.getAzureEndPoint())
                .credential(credential)
                .buildClient();

    //Get the blobContainerClient
    BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = 
            blobServiceClient.get().getBlobContainerClient(containerName);

    BlockBlobClient blockBlobClient = blobContainerClient
            .getBlobClient(bolbName)
            .getBlockBlobClient();

    //Setting Account Permission
    AccountSasPermission permissions = new AccountSasPermission()
            .setListPermission(true)
            .setReadPermission(true);

    //Following line is required if signature to be generated at container level
    //AccountSasResourceType resourceTypes = new AccountSasResourceType().setContainer(true);

    //In case you want to generate the signature at the object level use 
    AccountSasResourceType resourceTypes = new AccountSasResourceType().setObject(true);

    AccountSasService services = new AccountSasService().setBlobAccess(true).setFileAccess(true);

    //Valid for 2 days starting today
    OffsetDateTime expiryTime = OffsetDateTime.now().plus(Duration.ofDays(2));

    AccountSasSignatureValues sasValues =
            new AccountSasSignatureValues(expiryTime, permissions, services, resourceTypes);

    String sasToken = blobServiceClient.get().generateAccountSas(sasValues);
    sasToken = blockBlobClient.getBlobUrl()+"?"+sasToken;
    System.out.println("URL to get view the Blob in Browser "+sasToken); 
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("Error = {}",e.getMessage());
}
```